# ConfigParser - Same Option Loop

Tags: python, configparser

In each section of a config file I have multiple values of the same option. I want to loop through and run the same process each time for each option, is this possible with a ConfigParser?

[Section1]

> > SameSectionOptionName: Value
> >
> > SameSectionOptionName: Value

[Section2]

> > SameSectionOptionName: Value
> >
> > SameSectionOptionName: Value
> >
> > SameSectionOptionName: Value

[Section3]

> > SameSectionOptionName: Value

and so on

Regards,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using the ConfigParser module. It stores the configuration using case-insensitive dictionaries internally and in case of multiple same keys it will only provide the last encountered value, e.g.:

config.ini

```
[SomeSection]
SomeOption: Value 1
SomeOption: Value 2
SomeOption: Value 3
```

console

```
>>> import ConfigParser
>>> ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
<ConfigParser.ConfigParser instance at 0x10d4b91b8>
>>> c.read('config.ini')
['config.ini']
>>> c.get('SomeSection', 'SomeOption')
'Value 3'
>>> c.items('SomeSection')
[('someoption', 'Value 3')]
```